# Collectd only midterm

Tags: monitoring

I'm using `collectd` to monitor the status of my server.

In my plugin `LoadPlugin load`, it sends out 3 values:

- `.shortterm`
- `.midterm`
- `.longterm`

Is it possible to filter out `.shortterm` and `.longterm` so it will only send out `.midterm`?

How do you do this?

Comment: This what I already have but this blocks the hole load plugin ofcourse. The only thing is how can specifically block the longterm and shortterm?
Are these types, or wat parameter should i use?

LoadPlugin match_regex
<Chain "PostCache">
 <Rule>
  <Match regex>
   Plugin "^load$"
   Type ".*"
  </Match>
  Target stop
 </Rule>

 # Default Target
 Target "write"
</Chain>